# HTML colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, html, matplotlib

How do I use html to change colors in a plot using matplotlib in python? I tried

```
plt.plot(x,y,marker=".",color="#e0e0e0")
```

but this created the data points as "." but it also connects them with lines of #e0e0e0 color and I don't want these lines. I also tried

```
plt.plot(x,y,"#e0e0e0.")
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Then you need a scatterplot if you don't want lines.

Comment: @WayneWerner So I put ax.scatter instead of plt.plot ?

Comment: Why not try it, and find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to only have markers and no connecting lines between points you can use either

```
plt.plot(x, y, '.', color="#e0e0e0")
```

Here the third argument is a format string specifiying marker type and linestyle, and as no linestyle is specified no line is plotted. You can achieve the same effect with a more explicit notation using:

```
plt.plot(x, y, marker='.', linestyle='None', color="#e0e0e0")
```

`plt.scatter` also works as pointed out by the other commenters.